# Find numbers which are in a sequence(Minimum 3) with respect to another column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Check for my scenario in the screenshot shown below:

[image]

Comment: Just as a note: I hope you *are aware* that SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a sequence from each value and then subtract.  Then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by customer_id, artifact_number - seqnum) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by artifact_number) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```